# Django signals does not work with get_user_model()

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-signals

I am trying to add profile picture to user when user is created but upon creating user when I try to log in I get `User has no profile`, even when I try to log in into Django admin with superuser. This error is caused by `instance.profile.save()` in signals.py file.

Here is my signals.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  print('inside signals')
  print(created)
  if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  print('inside profile create')
  instance.profile.save()
```

Here is my Profile model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user.username} Profile"
```

Here is my register view:

```
User = get_user_model()


def register_view(request):
  form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)

  if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')

    try:
      user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    except:
      user = None

    if user != None:
      # request.user == user
      # login(request, user)
      return redirect('login')
    else:
      request.session['register_error'] = 1

  return render(request, "recipe/forms.html", {'form': form, 'title': 'Join Today'})
```

**EDIT**: Here is apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
  name = 'accounts'

  def ready(self):
    print('inside app')
    import accounts.signals
```

I did import `accounts.signals` under apps.py ready function and I do have `accounts.apps.AccountsConfig` under `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Commenting out `instance.profile.save()` will allow me to log in into Django admin, where I can see that users are been created through my register view, but no Profile are created.

Comment: Does this line gets executed: `  print('inside signals')`?

Comment: @AmirAfianian no it does not.

Comment: Please add the code to your `apps.py` as well.

Comment: @AmirAfianian I have added apps.py code. `inside app` do get print twice when I run `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: have you added the app config to your apps `__init__.py` in this form: `default_app_config = '<your_app_name>.apps.AccountsConfig'`?

Comment: @AmirAfianian just tried it that does not fix it, same error. Also, if I put `'<your_app_name>.apps.AccountsConfig'` directly to `INSTALLED_APPS` then I do not need to put it in `__init__.py`, I got this from other forum.